# Complement of open set

Tags: general-topology

In one of the lectures the following was stated: "Open sets are set that their complements are finite or the empty set, therefore closed set are finite set and X (the whole space)"

Why is it true? if we take $(0,1)\subset \mathbb{R}$ so $(0,1)^{c}=-(\infty,0]\cup [1,\infty)$ which is not finite.

Or maybe I wrote something worng?

Comment: I guess this is simply the definition of the *cofinite topology*, which can be defined on any set, not the order topology on $\mathbf R$.

Comment: He must be talking about a specific topology.  That is not true in general.  In all topopolgies the complements of open sets are precisely the closed sets.  So if this is true then he was talking about a topology where only finite sets are closed.  Such topologies exist but they are not general.

Comment: @Bernard, You have nailed it, before he talked about the cofinite, it did not seemed to be connected, but it is, thanks!

Comment: In such a topology, (0,1) would be neither open nor closed.